# Help with "Zelda Minihunt" puzzle

Tags: anagram, mazes

https://deusovi.github.io/puzzlefiles/zelda-minihunt.pdf

I don't have much puzzle experience

I think I solved "Wisdom" solution:

> jingle

I might have solved "Power" (I got:

> basher? But I don't understand how the grid works)

I'm stuck on "Courage" (It takes great courage to make it through mazelike dungeons full of traps.)

The progress I think I've made:

> now use [a] dead end

> we saw trap[s]

> [so] go to top left

> oxygen drafts? throw? in? tranq? qi?

> ??? thrill, north, troll, thwarts, lift, honor. I'm guessing you're supposed to be left with 6 letters.

Comment: What specific question are you asking? This reads like a progress log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you're asking how to solve Courage. Here's how I did it:

First, solve the maze as intended.

> You'll get "NOW GO TOP LEFT".

Follow the instruction through the new path:

> You'll get "NOW USE DEAD ENDS".

If you read the letters in those places, you'll get:

> "DRAW A LINE FROM Q TO Z"

And if you follow this last instruction:

> Connect both Q and Z with a straight line and you'll see it passes diagonally covering the letters THRUST,

which is the answer to this subpuzzle.